# Reusing swing components in Java

Tags: java, swing

If some component was changed after component was set to invisible, it is only repainted AFTER the component is set to visible. That makes flickers (old graphics is visible for a few milliseconds):

```
package test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class ReusingWindow extends JWindow {

    JLabel label;

    public ReusingWindow() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        label = new JLabel("Lazy cat");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));
        label.setBackground(Color.red);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(panel);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReusingWindow window = new ReusingWindow();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html>");
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
            sb.append("Not very lazy cat. Extremelly fast cat.<br>");
        }
         sb.append("</html>");

        while (true) {

            window.label.setText("Lazy cat");
            window.setVisible(true);
            pause();
            window.setVisible(false);
            pause();

            window.label.setText(sb.toString());
            window.setVisible(true);
            pause();
            window.setVisible(false);
            pause();
        }
    }

    private static void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReusingWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any solution besides creating the new window each time before setting it visible?

Comment: can't reproduce (win7, java7) - buuut: you are accessing the label off the EDT, which may produce any type of unwanted effects ... BTW: +1 for the SSCCE :-)

Comment: Try to look longer, sometimes it's OK, but sometimes old graphics is visible. But never mind - `update(getGraphics());` solved the problem :) Thanks everyone indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

Just need to `update(getGraphics());` (just an example):

```
while (true) {

        window.label.setText("Lazy cat");
        window.update(window.getGraphics());//<------ new line
        window.setVisible(true);
        pause();
        window.setVisible(false);
        pause();

        window.label.setText(sb.toString());
        window.update(window.getGraphics());//<------ new line
        window.setVisible(true);
        pause();
        window.setVisible(false);
        pause();
    }
```

[Here](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1758156?start=0&tstart=0) is very good info about the difference between `repaint()` and `update(Graphics g)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be somewhere with your "reusing window". With the simple class like

```
static class ReusingWindow extends JFrame {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    public ReusingWindow() {
        add(label);
        setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

I do not observe any flickering.

Comment: I intentionally made `JLabel`s to change the size to see what's happening. I still don't know how to prepare graphics before component is set to visible.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you call

```
    window.repaint();
```

manually before calling

```
   setVisible(true);
```

?
i cannot reproduce flickering on my machine.. if this didn't help you can try call

```
   window.revalidate();
```

aswell before repaint

Comment: As far as I know - components are not repainted if they are invisible. So it means when I set it to visible, ONLY THEN it is repainted - and I can see it.